# Converting from pdf to png with ghostscript, result with many white boxes

Tags: pdf, png, ghostscript

I'm converting pdf (created with adobe illustrator) into transparent png file, with following command:

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 -o target.png -f source.pdf
```

However, there's undesired white boxes in the resulting PNG, looks like it's auto generated by ghostscript, some bounding box. (see attached image)

[image]

Tryied both gs-9.05 and gs-9.10, same bad result.

I've tried to export to PNG file from Illustrator or Inkscape manually, the result is good.

[image]

What does Inkscape do to render it correct, and 
How could I eliminate those white boxes using ghostscript?

Answer (score 2):

Try **mudraw** of latest (1.3) muPDF, as far as I checked it creates nice PNGs from PDF files with 1.4 transparency:

```
mudraw -o out.png -c rgba in.pdf
```

"rgba" being, as you understand, RGB + alpha

Comment: mudraw is great to rasterize complicated vector graph. But for large output size (eg, 20000x20000), the memory consumption is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, you can't. PDF does support transparency, but the underlying media is always assumed to be white and opaque. So anywhere that marks are made on the medium is no longer transparent, its white.

You don't say which version of Ghostscript you are using, but if its earlier than 9.10 you could try upgrading.

Comment: Tried on 9.10, but no luck. Wonder how could inkscape done it right.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily look correct to me, the lower image has a grey circle in the medal, which is drawn as gold in the GS rendering. Seems to me one of them is wrong. I'm guessing that the lower image is rendered at a lower resolution because there are some nasty block artefacts in the various smooth shadings. The attachment of the ribbon to the medal looks plain wrong in the lower version.

Comment: Yeah, the output of Inkscape is incorrect (compared with Adobe Illustrator). Maybe I should turn to poppler, looks good so far, GS is too old and too slow.

Comment: Old ? The last release was a month ago. AS for slow, it is comparable to most PDF processors, and faster at higher resolutions. Which is reasonable considering its intended as a printing application. Frankly, if you want a PNG, don;t start by making a PDF file.